# Почему после функции system("pause") нет остановки?

Tags: c

почему в этом коде после:

```
A = getch();
printf("A = %c\n",A);
system("pause");
```

нету остановки после---> system("pause");

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос... А в какой ОС работаете?

Comment: А откуда вообще возникла идея, что `system("pause");` должно приводить к какой-то остановке?

Answer (score 2):

Первая версия - если код верный - что вы работаете, например, в Linux или еще где-то, где команды `pause` просто нет...

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно засыпание - используйте наитивные вызовы, например, sleep/usleep и т.д. так как они потребуют меньше системных вызовов, следовательно ресурсов жрать будут меньше

Comment: `system("pause");` - это очень распространенный паттерн среди новичков и sleep его не заменяет.

Comment: Ну, на счет того что не заменяет - как я понимаю остановки не происходит потому что system реализован как fork() с последующим exec(). И, по видимому, родительский процесс не дожидается завершения дочернего. Поэтому да, они не эквивалентны, но задача ведь именно ожидание, как я понимаю

Comment: `system("pause");` работает только в винде (в линуксе я не видел команды pause). А форка в винде нет. 

А вся эта конструкция нужна только для того, что бы не закрывалось консольное окошко. (о том, что по ctrl+f5 студия по умолчанию не закрывает окно, а в линуксе нормально запустить с отдельного терминала - новички обычно не знают)